# "I was used to do" vs. "I was used doing"

Tags: grammar, past-tense

Good day everyone,

Looked around and didn't find the desired answer to my question. Would you please be kind to give me a hand with the following:

"I was used to do..." or "I was used to swim here" 
                    vs 
"I was used doing..." or "I was used swimming in here"

Are they all correct?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid those are all wrong: it has to be ***I was used to doing***. Perhaps you were confusing this with *I used to do*, which is also correct but has a slightly different meaning.

Comment: so, saying "I was used to do" is not correct I must add "ing"?

Comment: @Neylian: Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Cerberus: what, then, is the 'slight difference' in meaning there is between "someone used to do something" and "someone was used to doing something". I would be grateful if you could elaborate on it since, as a foreigner, I do not have the feel for this slight difference.

Comment: @Cerberus: I think the queston is worth re-opening.

Comment: @Cerberus: why say "has a slightly different meaning" without stating that difference? A former habit (changed today) for "sb used to do sth" and a habit someone had in the past without any reference to what that habit has become in the present time for "sb was used to doing sth" That would have made your answer even more helpful!

Answer (score -1):

> I was used to her jokes.

It means that I *adapted*/*adjusted* to her jokes (so i.e. I didn't get offended).

> I was used to doing ...

This is wrong based on English grammar.

Do not confuse `used to do something` with `be used to doing something`. These are totally different, and for the first one you must always use an infinite after `used to`, not past tense or the `ing` form. The second one is just the same as the first sentence explained above.

See the grammar note from LDOCE below:

[image]

> I used to swim here.

It refers to the routine you had in the past that you don't have anymore. So, e.g. as a child you *used to* swim in the lake every day, but you don't do it anymore.

Comment: so to say "I was used to drive" is not a correct way? I must say "I was used to driving" - Am I getting this correct?

Comment: Yes! Exactly. *I was used to driving, because I hated the public transport, however now, I'm used to cycling, since it's a good exercise and costless.*

Comment: I see, I was trying to put 2 different things into one. Would it be correct if I would say "however now, I got used to cycle "

Comment: “I was used to [infinitive]” is not at all wrong, it just means something else: it is a passive form of _use_ in the sense ‘employ’. “The stolen car was used to help the robbers escape the crime scene”, for example. You also seem to be saying that “I was used to doing…” is ungrammatical, which is of course not at all true.